# Solving definite Integrals given the value of a part of the Integral

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I have a problem that how I can apply integration by parts on in the form
$$\int _{b}^{a} udv$$ I have been given

$$\int _{b}^{a} dv=\frac{\sqrt{\pi }}{2}$$

If I apply the integration by parts formula I get

$$I\ =\ [ uv]_{b}^{a} -\int _{b}^{a} vdu$$

Is the following expression true?

$$[ uv]_{b}^{a} =[ u]_{b}^{a} \times [ v]_{b}^{a}$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. How do you define $[uv]_a^b$?

Comment: $u( a) v( a) -u( b) v( b)$

Comment: Sure about that? I would say that it is $u(b)v(b)-u(a)v(a)$.

Comment: You have two multiplications in your expression - are they different? If, no, then, based on how you define $[ uv]_{b}^{a} $ we have $u(b)v(b)-u(a)v(a)\ne (u(b)-u(a))(v(b)-v(a))$.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to apply integration by parts to $\int _{a}^{b} dv=\frac{\sqrt{\pi }}{2}$, then you have $u=1$, which gives $du=0$, so you obtain
$$\int \limits_{a}^{b} dv=[ uv]_{a}^{b} -\int\limits _{a}^{b} vdu= [ v]_{a}^{b}=b-a=\frac{\sqrt{\pi }}{2}  $$

Answer (score 0):

> Is the following expression true?
>
> $[uv]^a_b=[u]^a_b×[v]^a_b$

**No.**
Using the definition of limit of integration, we can express LHS as
\begin{equation}
[uv]^a_b=u(a)v(a)-u(b)v(b)
\end{equation}
similarly, RHS becomes
\begin{equation}
[u]^a_b×[v]^a_b=[u(a)-u(b)][v(a)-v(b)]=u(a)v(a)-u(a)v(b)-u(b)v(a)+u(b)v(b)
\end{equation}
It shouldn't be hard to see that these two are generally not equivalent. I believe the source of your error comes from not treating $u,v$ as functions, but rather like variables.